# Two different timeouts in same loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a web crawler that is working fine, but i have an issue. What I basically need is when I reach 90 requests I need to give a timeout of 5 or more minutes.

my example code:

```
for (let i=0; i < maxPag; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i);
        getInfoPage(i);

    }, 15000 * (i+1));
}
```

For example in the example above i give a timeout but is for the page that is requested, but after 90 requests, i need to have like a bigger timeout, this happens in all times that i reach in 90 requests.

How can i make a interval in the 90th request, than in 180th request, and goes on untill my for loop ends.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, you want your timeout after every 90 request to be 5 minutes?

Answer (score 2):

You could use one loop that waits longer at every 90th iteration:

```
 const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

 (async function() {
    for(let i = 0; i < maxPag; i++) {
       if(i && !(i % 90)) {
          await timer(5 * 60 *1000);
       } else {
           await timer(15000);
       }
       getInfoPage(i);
    }
 })();
```

Comment: I think the OP wants 15 seconds before each request, and then additionally 5 minutes after every 90 requests.

Comment: Don't forget to add the `round * 90 * 15000` milliseconds that each round itself takes to the timeouts in the outer loop

Comment: @bergi I guess its better if I just remove that version conpletely

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the `async`/`await` approaches, you can use the following solution with the naive `setTimeout` scheduling:

```
for (let i=0; i < maxPag; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i);
        getInfoPage(i);

    }, 15000 * (i+1) + 300000 * Math.floor(i / 90));
//     ^^^^^           ^^^^^^
// 15s between each    5m between chunks of 90
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest, cleanest and recommended solution is to use a recursive function:

```
var i = 0;
var BATCH_SIZE = 90;
var TIMEOUT_NORMAL = 15000;
var TIMEOUT_LONG =  300000;

function crawl() {
    // Your crawling code
    console.log(i);
    getInfoPage(i);

    // Schedule next call (if there are still pages left)
    if (++i < maxPag) {
        // Use the longer timeout if "i" is divisible by 90
        setTimeout(crawl, i % BATCH_SIZE ? TIMEOUT_NORMAL : TIMEOUT_LONG);
    }
}

// Start the crawler
crawl();
```

Using recursive functions for timeout gives you the most control of the loop and also makes the code easier to understand.

I used the index `i` as a global variable in order to simplify the `setTimeout` call and also the code will be more efficient as you don't have to pass any parameters and save any variables on the stack. Note that it is not recommended to have globally defined variables as I did above, you should write all of them in a namespace, eg:

```
var crawlOpts = {
    currentIndex: 0,
    BATCH_SIZE: 90,
    TIMEOUT_NORMAL: 15000,
    TIMEOUT_LONG:  300000,
}
```

And access them like `crawlOpts.BATCH_SIZE` or `crawlOpts.currentIndex++`.

Answer (score 0):

use `async/await` and run function recursively:

```
console.clear()
const maxPag = 10000;
const timeoutAfter = 10;
const timeoutTime = 1000


const timeout = ()=>new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve, timeoutTime))
const run = async (i=0) => {
    console.log(i)
    getInfoPage(i);
    if (i%timeoutAfter === 0){
      await timeout()
    }
    run(++i)
}

run()
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6sz3tfq/)

Comment: Why do it recursively when you have `async`/`await`?

Comment: Just another solution. Actually for some reason I thought that `for` loop will not wait for async functions so I found this solution with recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
let extraTimeOut = 0

for (let i = 0; i < maxPag; i++) {
  if(i && i % 90 === 0) {
    extraTimeOut += 300000
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
    getInfoPage(i);

  }, 1500 * (i + 1) + extraTimeOut);
}
```

Comment: You have to add up the timeouts, and this will also wait longer before doing the first request.

Comment: Honestly, I did not get it clearly is `15000 * (i+1)`  needed as well and plus after every 90 mins additional timeout? So if it is, in this case why is my solution bad?

Comment: You will want to declare `let timeout = 0` outside of the loop and then `timeout += 15000` inside the loop body so that your method of adding `300000` works.

Comment: @Bergi I modified my answer. Can you please explain why declaring extraTimeOut inside for loop would not work?I thought I understand how execution stack and event loop works and this happens . :/

Comment: When you had both the `let timeOut = 15000 * (i+1);` declaration and the `timeOut = timeOut + 300000` conditional update inside the loop, the variable would get reset on every iteration and the 5 mins would not be applied continously.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you! Actually there was my misunderstanding of the task that caused my confusion and I mixed up. In my previous example, I didn’t think that after 90 requests every request has to add the extra timeout. I thought it was only for 90th and 180th. So fortunately nothing was wrong with my understanding how js works. Thank you for your time. I really learned more from yesterday!